# Incorrect array depth when saving custom field

Tags: entities

I have a module that implements all necessary hooks for a custom field api. I can see hook_field_validate() and hook_field_is_empty() working properly and values are also available on hook_pre_save() but with incorrect depth.

For example on hook_field_validate my $items array have:

```
161 (Array, 2 elements)
  0 (Array, 3 elements)
    token (String, 15 characters ) test_parameters
    target_id (String, 3 characters ) 161
    value (String, 2 characters ) X1
```

And on hook_pre_save() my field have:

```
field_parameters_values (Array, 1 element)
  und (Array, 1 element)
    0 (Array, 2 elements)
      0 (Array, 3 elements)
        token (String, 15 characters ) test_parameters
        target_id (String, 3 characters ) 161
        value (String, 2 characters ) X1
```

so there is a level more on the resulting array, it can be easily manipulated here but I want to understand the reason for that.

My hook_widget_form() consists in something like:

```
(...)
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
  (...)

  $element[$custom_id][$delta]['token'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $token,
  );
  $element[$custom_id][$delta]['target_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $custom_id,
  );
  $element[$custom_id][$delta]['value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $token,
    '#required' => $instance['required'],
    '#default_value' => '',
  );
  $delta++;
}
```

Comment: Why `$element[$custom_id][$delta]['target_id']` instead of the usual `$element['target_id']`? That's definitely what's causing the problem, but I'm not sure why you're trying to wrap the widgets in extra array levels in the first place?

Comment: @Clive Hi Clive, thank you for your comment, I'm using the $delta for differentiating from multiple elements, without it will only have one element.